# Dynamics of probability of hitting a barrier

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, brownian-motion, finance, stopping-times

Consider stochastic process $\{V_t\}$ that follows a Geometric Brownian motion
$$dV_t = \mu V_t dt + \sigma V_t dZ_t$$
where $Z_t$ is a standard Brownian motion.

Consider the process $\{P_t\}$ where $P_t$ is the probability that the process $\{V_t\}$ hits a constant barrier $V_b$ between $t$ and $t + dt$. Is it possible to derive the dynamics of $P_t$?

Comment: Do you mean between $t$ and $t+T$? I think between $t$ and $t+dt$ is not well defined. Then you can use reflection principle.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Why is it not well defined? I was expecting it to be something like either 0 or 1. Between t and t+T, can you point to a reference for the derivation (or derive it here)?

Comment: Well what is the precise meaning of between $t$ and $t+dt$? If it well-defined it should be zero as GBM is a smooth process. For the latter this should be useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_principle_(Wiener_process).

Comment: One way to look at this is to compute the following: $$h(t) \equiv - \frac{\partial \log P[\tau > t| \mathcal{F}_t]}{\partial t}$$ where $\tau$ is the stopping time and $\mathcal{F}_t$ is the filtration up to time $t$. If I understand correctly, it should be $h(t) \in \{0, \infty\}$ and it should be a submartingale (hence my hope for a representation of the dynamics).